# Azure Devops Services - Query does not display custom field value

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem, azure-devops-services

I have a query of work items and include custom field (tried with boolean field and with string Picklist).
Query results does not  display the value of these fields .

My process is hosted XML on Azure DevOps services

XML of field

```
  <FIELD name="X meeting completed" refname="X.Xmeetingcompleted" type="Boolean" reportable="dimension">
        <HELPTEXT>System Validation is Needed</HELPTEXT>
  </FIELD>

  <Control FieldName="X.Xmeetingcompleted" Type="FieldControl" Label="X meeting completed" LabelPosition="Left" />

<Control Label="X meeting completed" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="X.Xmeetingcompleted" />
```

Query

[image]

Result

[image]

Field value

[image]

I have tried adding the field to the query and recreating the field.
Recreated the query - without any success.

Comment: Silly question: What does it show when it's `true`? Anything?

Comment: when it is true it is the same

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the default value to your field:

```
<DEFAULT from="value" value="False" />
```

Use this guidance: [Add a checkbox or Boolean field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/add-modify-field?view=azure-devops-2022&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops#add-a-checkbox-or-boolean-field)

Comment: still not showing the value.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is by [design](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Query-does-not-display-custom-field-defa/10091034?q=Azure%20Devops%20Services%20-%20Query%20does%20not%20display%20custom%20field%20value)  according to Microsoft.

The Solution supplied there is to [Bulk Update](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/How-do-I-do-a-bulk-update-on-multiple-TF/678110?q=bulk%20update%20workitems%20) the query and force a save on all the query items

> We could do a bulk update at web portal or use Azure DevOps Open in
> Excel extension.
>
> 1. Web portal:
>
> To start a bulk edit, begin by multi-selecting the work items you want
> to modify, either from the query results or the backlog. Choose Edit
> from the context menu of the selected work items. Enter a value for
> each field that you want to update. From the Query results page, you
> must save all work items that you bulk-modified. When you bulk modify
> items from the backlog, they are automatically saved.
>
> 2. Excel:
>
> Select the work items you want to update in the query or the backlog.
> Right click and choose 'Open in Excel', then select 'Choose Columns'
> in the Excel and edit the value. Publish your worksheet.

could not find any other method